# Difference between "eat rice" and "have rice"

Tags: differences

Consider the following 2 questions:

> 1. Do you eat rice for breakfast in the morning?
> 2. Do you have rice for breakfast in the morning?

My questions are:

Are both questions acceptable? If they are, are there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can both mean the same thing, but it all depends on context.

Both sentences can mean:

> Is rice one of foods you typically eat during your morning breakfast?

However, Question #2 could mean something different. Let's say I was staying at your house overnight, and I was on a special diet that required me to have rice in the morning for breakfast. I might ask you:

> Do you have rice for breakfast in the morning?

which, in that context, could be paraphrased as:

> Is there any rice in your pantry, so that we can cook it for breakfast in the morning?

Because the word *have* has more than one meaning (only one of which is synonymous with *eat*), the second question can mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable as we all know that breakfast is when you eat, and that rice is a food, so there's very little difference in meaning.

Comment: +1 for *Both are acceptable*; -1 for *there's very little difference in meaning*.